Get execution time of symfony http client
I want to get the number of seconds an http request takes. I have this code:
$starttime = microtime(true);

$response = $this->httpClient->request(
    'POST',
    $endpoint,
    [
        'headers' => $header,
        'body' => $inputXml
    ]
);

sleep(2);
$endtime = microtime(true);
$timeDiffInSeconds = ($endtime - $starttime);

the request takes around 3 seconds, plus the sleep time, in postman I see 5,08s, that looks correct. But in PHP I $timeDiffInSeconds is float(2.0008609294891).
is http client async?, how can I see the real execution time?.
is there a parameter in the http client that shows the time it took?

According to the docs "Responses are always asynchronous, so that the call to the method returns immediately instead of waiting to receive the response:"
https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html

The request is async, so in order to wait, we need to ask for info about the response, for example:
$statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();

This fixed my issue.
